# Control not coming inside divobject.children().on({'mousedown' ...});

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get focus inside a particular ‘section’ inside a div on mouse click. I have written the following lines of code:

```
$('#my-div-id').children('.my-section-class').on({
    'mousedown' : function(e){
        var $item = $(this);
        $item.focus();
    }       
});
```

The sections are added inside a for loop inside the div based on some if statements.

There are five sections of the class ‘my-section-class’ inside the div and `$('#my-div-id').children('.my-section-class').length` is returning 5. But control never comes inside my function.

In the above code if I am ignoring the `.children('.my-section-class')`, control goes inside my function whenever I click inside the div. But I want to focus the particular section and not the entire div.

I have tried `$('#my-div-id').children('.my-section-class').live('click',function(event)` also, but this is giving the same behavior. I am getting control inside my function if I hard code the ID of a particular section instead of using the `children()` function.

**Edit**

The html code is added using a `<c:forEach>` tag and looks like this 
`<c:ForEach ...>
    <section class="my-section-class">...</section>
    </c:ForEach>`

Comment: Could you please create a jsFiddle or provide the HTML markup? Thanks

Comment: is the `my-section-class` elements added dynamically

Comment: also jquery version used

Comment: jQuery version is 1.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#my-div-id').on('mousedown', '.my-section-class', function(e) {
    var $item = $(this);
    $item.focus();
});
```

Comment: With this it works. Could you please tell me why my code didnt work in this case?

Comment: if you are dealing with dynamic elements, you need to use event delegation to register event handlers